# How to escape JSON in the URL using postman?

Tags: json, postman

The Json string I am trying to pass as a parameter using Postman is:
{"event":"hello","data":"Smith"}

so in Postman, the above Json string for the GET would be appended below:

http://localHost:8080/....../foo?jasonRequest?{"event":"hello","data":"Smith"}

I'm getting HTTP Status 500 - java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index.

I've tried escaping the double quotes, but still no luck.

Comment: put json file or data in body

Comment: @brykneval being a `GET` request, it doesn't have an option for `body`.

Comment: thankx that works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Your request has 2 `?`. A `GET` request should only have one, after which the parameters are defined.
In Potman, you can add parameters by clicking the `Params` button and introduce one parameter per row:

[image]

Postman will automatically add those parameters to the request.
I assumed that the endpoint is `foo/jasonRequest`.

Hope this helps.